# β sign - HTML version?

Tags: html

What is HTML representation (like e.g. `&nbsp;`) of β sign?

Comment: Instead of relying on entities you definitely should set what character encoding you use in HTML and simply include the characters directly.

Comment: No, I'm not asking for the code without a reason... I need it for compatibility

Answer (score 2):

You could specify it as `&#946;`, but a simple `β` is much more readable. It just requires that you get your [character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/) straight.

Comment: `&Beta;` helped - I need it for compatibility

Comment: If you need it for 'compatibility' then you probably don't have your character encodings straight, and you should fix that problem instead of trying to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

You write `&beta;` as [described here](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/BetaCharacterEntity).

Answer (score 0):

```
&#946;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp

Comment: @David Dorward - Hmm, while I approve of the idea of w3fools, it would be good if they got their own facts right. For example, they claim "Named anchors have been deprecated since HTML4". Named anchors were not deprecated in HTML4 - ids on other elements were just added as an alternative.

Comment: It's a new site, so errors are probably inevitable, although sad under the circumstances. I suggest telling them about the problems so they can fix it.

Comment: @Alohci - I don't mean to be a smartass, but pull up a w3c article, you can find several errors per - one in that site isn't a good comparison at all, since w3schools has tens of thousands of *very* egregious errors and just bad coding standards, pick a common SO question that comes up, `setTimeout()`, [look at what w3schools has](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) `setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);`...is that good practice?

Comment: @Alohci - One more *very* misunderstood thing, `for(...in...)` loops on arrays, [what does w3schools say?](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) On the *very first line*: "The for...in statement loops through the elements of an array or through the properties of an object."  This is a *very* inaccurate description, "loops through" is non-specific and this should **not** be used on Arrays...but the question comes up often, and it's likely the bad information the askers got originated there.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Sure, as I say I do approve of the idea of w3fools. I have commented a number of times on SO about the terrible advice given by w3schools. My own personal bugbear is their advice on XHTML, which, as far as I can see, at no point ever mentions content types or gives any indication that, for example, `<script src="example.com" />` will fail horribly in text/html.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

Hex:

```
&#x03B2;
```

Dec:

```
&#946;
```

UTF-8:

```
β
```

Taken [from here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/guide/entities.html).

Answer (score 0):

Typing this in your location bar (tested on Firefox):

```
javascript:alert('&#' + 'β'.charCodeAt(0) + ';');
```

gives

```
&#946;
```

Next time you want to know what HTML code it is for a character, use this.